# SailsJs self is not defined in production.min.js

Tags: sails.js, production

I created a small Application using SailsJs Framework v1.2.3.

There is no issue in debug mode (sails lift). However when I lift the solution in production, the layout is displayed as well as pages with pure text (e.g. default FAQ page) but login page cannot be rendered (I still see the layout). My production is on port 80 at the moment as I'm trying to have a fully working production on my local machine before deploying it.

The browser console has the following error:

> production.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: self is not defined
>     at production.min.js:1
>     at production.min.js:1

I'm using the following dependencies in my project, the rest is from the sails new project WebApp option.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "csv-parser": "^2.3.2",
    "sails": "^1.2.3",
    "sails-hook-apianalytics": "^2.0.3",
    "sails-hook-organics": "^0.16.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-hook-uploads": "^0.4.3"
  },
```

Anyone could help me understanding what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna take a look at `.sailsrc` the original file must be

```
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "_generatedWith": {
    "sails": "1.2.3",
    "sails-generate": "1.16.13"
  }
}
```

last time i config this file to make another folder public and i have a same problem